# Free massive propagator as an OPE?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator, asymptotics

Consider a free massive propagator $$G(p)\equiv\frac{1}{p^2+m^2}$$
There is a 'naive' expansion in terms of the mass
$$G(p)\sim\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n \frac{m^{2n}}{p^{2(n+1)}}$$
This expansion might be interesting because there are theories which are written in terms of massless fields in the Lagrangian but non-perturbatively their propagator picks up a mass which does not appear in perturbation theory since it is non-analytic in the coupling constant (something like $m\sim e^{-1/g}$). So this expansion looks a little like an operator product expansion where each power $m^{2n}$ might be the vacuum expectation value of some operator $\langle O_n \rangle\sim m^{2n}$.

Now what I just described was a little sketchy, but this apparently exactly works out in the $O(N)$ sigma model at the lowest order of the large $N$ expansion in dimension $d=2$. The bosonic fields are massless in the Lagrangian but in the large $N$ limit their propagator is exactly of the free form $G(p)$ and it can be expanded in terms of VEVs of operators that give the mass $m^2$. This was shown in [F. David, Nuclear Physics B209 (1982) 433](https://inspirehep.net/literature/180041)

My problem is that the expansion of $G(p)$ in terms of $m^2$ is not the obvious one above. Instead it is something that I am finding difficult to derive or even interpret. It is equation (2.13) in the paper above:

$$G(p)=\sum^\infty_{n=0} (-1)^n m^{2n}\text{P.H.}\left[\frac{1}{p^{2(n+1)}}\right]+a_n(d)\Delta^n\delta(p)\int\frac{d^d k}{(2\pi)^d}\frac{k^{2n}}{k^2+m^2}$$
Apparently "P.H." stands for "Hadamard's finite part" and $$a_n(d)\equiv \frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}d)}{\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}d)2^n(n!)^2}$$
This equation wasn't derived in that paper. Instead the reader is referred to another very general and technical paper in which it never explicitly appears ([M.C. Bergere, F. David, Annals Phys. 142 (1982) 416](https://inspirehep.net/literature/12207)). But surely to understand the asymptotic expansion of a simple free propagator I don't need to understand their whole formalism for dealing with possibly divergent multiloop Feynman diagrams (do I?)

How do you derive this asymptotic expansion of a free massive propagator which is directly connected to the operator product expansion?